# I can not trigger jquery event on div append in the parent window by the popup window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a check box on page1 when I click on that the Popup opened.After that when I click on the  button in pop window  the ajax run and append the data(a checkbox) in parent i.e page1.But when I close the popup and want to trigger the jquery event on the  newly added check box in teh page 1 It does not reflect any event.
Please let me know which function I have to used to trigger the event

Comment: You should take a look at event delegation: https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: i assume that there is a close button? maybe just add an onclick event for the close button?

Comment: Thanks for you reply .I have added that But it is not working .It works only if the ajax is run on same page.In my case it is running on popup window.

Comment: no ajax is not running on the close button.There is a check box in popup window

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you append new HTML to a page you must then reapply your JQuery event to that new html element.

here is an example of what I mean.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(document).on('click', 'a checkbox', function(){});
});
```

This is the first delegation of the click event. This is the only time an `a checkbox` will have this event assigned to it.

if you then append a new `a checkbox` to the document, you must then call.

**edit:** Based on Alvaro Hernandorena's comment.

```
//First unbind the a checkbox events so you don't get multiple attached to a single element.
$(document).off('click', 'a checkbox', function(){});
// Then reattach the events to a checkbox
$(document).on('click', 'a checkbox', function(){});
```

again. Which will then attach the JQuery event to the newly created `a checkbox`

Comment: if you append content multiple times you should place an unbind command to avoid multiple listeners